# Fail to start MobileFirst development server

Tags: eclipse, vmware

I have the following environment:

Windows 7 64-bit OS;
Eclipse Kepler SR2 32-bit + JDK 1.7 32-bit;
MobileFirst Platform Studio 6.3 20150106-1717

When I opened my eclipse I clicked on the green play button to start the development server, I got the following errors; or if I create a simple project and attempt to deploy it on the dev server, same errors come out; or if I delete the server and create a new one and then try to start it; or if I install 64-bit eclipse with 64-bit Java 7:

```
com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.LaunchException: Caught unexpected exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.internal.KernelBootstrap.rethrowException(KernelBootstrap.java:418)
at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.internal.KernelBootstrap.go(KernelBootstrap.java:183)
at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.Launcher.createPlatform(Launcher.java:131)
at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:55)
at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.cmdline.EnvCheck.main(EnvCheck.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.cmdline.Utils.getInstallDir(Utils.java:38)
at com.ibm.ws.kernel.productinfo.ProductInfo.getAllProductInfo(ProductInfo.java:53)
at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.internal.KernelBootstrap.getProductInfoDisplayName(KernelBootstrap.java:395)
at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.internal.KernelBootstrap.go(KernelBootstrap.java:119)
... 3 more
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 10777
CWWKE0005E: The runtime environment could not be launched.
CWWKE0018E: An exception occurred while launching the runtime environment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
```

I tried everything but no luck, so please diagnose this issue, thanks.

Comment: Are you working in a virtual host or a VM or on a network share where the workspace is not in the same physical space as Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I'm using VMWare, this is running on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unrelated to MobileFirst Platform, and may be instead related to the problem described in the following IBM tech note: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21584343

It is unclear from the question and comments if the workspace is in a different network drive than the Eclipse folder. If yes, consider placing both in the the same "physical location".

Answer (score 0):

I did realize my system location was out of sync thus I did open the `jvm.options` file and copy pasted the below configuration

```
-Dibm.worklight.admin.db.type=DERBY
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Duser.language=en
-Duser.country=US
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dwas.debug.mode=true
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=10777
-Dcom.ibm.websphere.ras.inject.at.transform=true
-Dcom.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.client.rest.readTimeout=180000
-Dibm.worklight.admin.db.type=DERBY
-Xmx1024m
-Dos.name=Windows
-DwlSyncStart=false
-Dibm.worklight.rhino.debug=transport=socket,address=9000
```

Which worked in my case , all the best.